Faulty BMS diode identification



I had a short in the light circuit, resulting in the battery not outputting at full charge. I found a diode with a short, so I need help to identify it for replacement.

Can you see any SMD code on the diode?  It must be a Zener as Z01

Unfortunately nothing visable definitely zoomed in on all angles but nothing illegible

Hard to reverse engineer this photo, but could be a zener for gating input FET limiting Vout max to the string of charger to bat.
